# Are partitions of unity needed in manifolds to define a measure coinciding with the Lebesgue measure under coordinate systems?

Tags: measure-theory, smooth-manifolds

Consider a Hausdorff smooth manifold $M^n$. In the book Riemannian Geometry by Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine, proposition 6.1.4 reads as follows:

> If $M$ is compact (or locally compact and countable at infinity), there always exists a density. (...)

In such context, I understand that the idea for defining a density would be: let $\{\rho_i\}$ be a partition of unity strictly subordinate to a smooth atlas $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$. Given a local chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ and a Lebesgue measurable $E \subset \phi_i(U_i)$, define $\mu_i(E)=\sum_j \int_{\phi_i(U_i \cap U_j)} \rho_j \chi_E dm=m(E)$, where m is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I understand that such definition allows us to prove the second axiom of densities. (i.e., the Change of Variables Theorem holds for continuous functions supported on the intersection of local charts)

On the other hand, it does not seem clear to me whether the definition $\mu_i(E)=m(E)$ would likewise define a density for a non-paracompact $M$. In other words, my question is: could we use such definition and obtain a density in a non-paracompact manifold?

Edit: the problem was that I guessed the idea for defining the density wrongly! The correct definition for a measurable $E \subset \phi_i(U_i)$ would be $\mu_i(E)=\sum_j \int_{\phi_j(U_j)} \chi_{\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}(E)} (\rho_j \circ \phi_j^{-1}) dm \neq m(E)$, which is reasonable, as it takes into account how the volume is deformed through the diffeomorphisms between charts.